# Good text-to-speech resource for learning Hebrew

Tags: self-learning, hebrew

So I was sent here to ask my question from [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com).

I'm currently into my third month of learning Hebrew. I have been using the very limited text-to-speech dictionary from hebrewpod101.com to look up translations when I need to. Since Hebrew is very difficult, I really need the audio when learning to say the words.

I have not been very successful in finding a decent text-to-speech dictionary for English to Hebrew. Does anyone know of any websites or apps I can purchase/download/view with a good text-to-speech dictionary?

I don't mind if it's for Biblical Hebrew or modern day Hebrew as modern day Hebrew is fairly similar to Biblical Hebrew.

Comment: This isn't text-to-speech, but it has to do with audio sources: teachmehebrew.com has audio for everything on that website. Seems like you would appreciate it.

Comment: @AML okay, not exactly what I'm looking for but I'll definitely add it to my resources. Thank you.

Comment: Now that I think about it more, the closest thing to what you want that I know of is an online dictionary by Rav-Milim: https://www.ravmilim.co.il/. I think it costs $100 per year. I used to subscribe to it. The main benefit, compared to other dictionaries, is that you can enter almost any word (including conjugated verbs and in-combination with prepositions), and it will give you the word with nikkud. This is in contrast to Morfix, for example, which doesn't do anything even close to that. Since this isn't text-to-speech, though, I won't use this as an answer. Great resource.

Comment: @AML Ah okay - לא רע בכלל. I'll check that out too. Does it have audio with each entered word?

Comment: I don't think they have audio for each word.

Comment: @AML darn -- oh well it's okay. Another resource is great. תודה רבה

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I have found forvo.com, which has a [Hebrew pronunciation dictionary](https://forvo.com/languages/he/).

For the most part, this site has been extremely helpful and very extensive. I recommend forvo.com for auditory for Hebrew.

Comment: Also, it has pronunciation dictionaries for many other languages, seems like a very useful tool. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyL very cool! I did not know that. Enjoy!